# Cite in theorem environment argument

Tags: macros, errors, citing, optional-arguments

When I try to cite a book in such a way

```
\begin{theorem}[\cite[p.~90]{bibitem}]
Theorem body.
\end{theorem}
```

I've got an error because of multiple use of `[` and `]`. Is it possible to cite in such a way in theorem argument? Would be great if it could be done without redefine of `\cite` command.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you need to pass a `]` inside an optional argument, just enclose the argument in figure braces:

```
\begin{theorem}[{\cite[p.~90]{bibitem}}]
Theorem body.
\end{theorem}
```

Without this, it's the `\cite[p.~90` (everything up to the first `]`) that gets passed as the argument, while the remaining text is typeset afterwards.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out _why_ this happens.  The `[` and `]` bracketing of optional arguments in LaTeX isn't as robust as the `{ ... }` bracketing of TeX.  In particular, `[` is matched by the *next* `]` that is in the same group (with regard to `{ ... }` grouping) as it.  It doesn't look to see if the `]` should have matched an intervening `[`.  The solution is (as Andrey says) to ensure that any intervening `[` and `]`s are in a different TeX group by enclosing them in braces.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Andrey Vihrov perfectly addresses the OP, I just want to add a small note (which doesn't fit well in a comment): when using the package `ntheorem` and the `\theoremstyle{plain}` command, wrapping the citation in braces is not enough. This is basically due to the implementation of the theorem style, which is the following:

```
\newtheoremstyle{plain}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}
```

The `\cite` command will be the `##3` argument. If the `\cite` command comes with an optional parameter (as in the OP) this interferes with the `\item` brackets. The same issue occurs with the `change`, `margin`, `nonumberplain`, and `empty` theorem styles. As a workaround, you may either wrap the `\cite` command in double braces, e.g.

```
\begin{theorem}[{{\cite[p.~90]{bibitem}}}]
Theorem body.
\end{theorem}
```

or you may consider redefining the style wrapping the `##3` argument in braces. For example, you can redefine the plain style using

```
\renewtheoremstyle{plain}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\ ({##3})\theorem@separator]}
```