# Why does LaTeX parse square brackets differently than curly braces?

Tags: brackets, braces, parsing

In [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13945/cite-in-theorem-environment-argument?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment25717_13946) (copied below without effort to preserve formatting):

> It may be worth pointing out why this happens. The [ and ] bracketing of optional arguments in LaTeX isn't as robust as the { ... } bracketing of TeX. In particular, [ is matched by the next ] that is in the same group (with regard to { ... } grouping) as it. It doesn't look to see if the ] should have matched an intervening [. The solution is (as Andrey says) to ensure that any intervening [ and ]s are in a different TeX group by enclosing them in braces. – Loop Space Mar 21 '11 at 8:09

it's stated that LaTeX parses square brackets different than TeX processes curly braces.  Are there any design reasons for this?  Was it just because it was simpler to program this way?  Is the same thing true in other standard variants of TeX (XeTeX, LuaTeX, ...)?

Comment: By default `{` and `}` are catcode 1 and 2 respectively, but `[` and `]` are just regular non-alphabetic characters (catcode 12). So this alone will cause them to be treated differently. So braces are really the only grouping characters built in to TeX. (And of course, since catcodes can be changed, one could in principle make any type of character the grouping characters.)

Comment: Why was this a comment and not an answer? It is the answer. With perhaps the clarification that matching and nesting the grouping characters - whatever characters have category codes 1 and 2, but usually the braces - is built into TeX. While TeX's macros can take arguments *delimited* by other characters, such as '[' and ']', there is no matching across nesting performed.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau Because it was late, and I wasn't sure if it was enough of an answer. :)

Comment: @DonaldArseneau And I can't speak to the design philosophy part of the question.

Comment: See also: [syntax - \] inside an optional argument - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99495/inside-an-optional-argument)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TeX recognizes only two grouping characters. These are the characters assigned the catcodes 1 (begin group) and 2 (end group). By default they are `{` and `}` respectively.  The `[` and `]` characters are just regular non-alphabetic characters assigned to catcode 12. For more information about TeX catcodes see [What are category codes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16410/2693).

Because of this, only braces (or more properly, the catcode 1 and 2 characters) are matched; everything else, including arguments delimited by `[` `]` or `(` `)` or `|` (to use some real examples) are dealt with completely differently, usually using something like TeX's delimited argument definitions, which cannot deal with nesting directly. For more information about delimited arguments, see [How does TeX look for delimited arguments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438359/2693) and [Why does TeX remove braces around delimited arguments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39882/2693).

As egreg notes in the comments, commands defined using the `xparse` package are able to deal with nested `[ ]` in optional arguments. Here's a small example showing how they work differently.

Here I've defined two seemingly identical commands, one using `\newcommand` and one using `xparse`'s `\NewDocumentCommand`. They each take a single optional argument. I've used colours to show  how the commands parse the arguments.

To show how each command works with nested `[ ]` we can try to make the first optional argument the string `[Arg1]`. If our command worked correctly, it should make the string `[Arg1]` red, and the string `[Arg2]` blue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\regularcmd}[2][]{{\color{red}#1}{\color{blue}#2}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\xparsecmd}{o m}{{\color{red}#1}{\color{blue}#2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item\regularcmd[[Arg1]]{[Arg2]}

\item\regularcmd[{[Arg1]}]{[Arg2]}

\item\xparsecmd[[Arg1]]{[Arg2]}

\item\xparsecmd[{[Arg1]}]{[Arg2]}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

As you can see from the output item 1, the regularly defined command fails to do this. Instead it stops parsing the optional argument at the first `]` it encounters, and then takes the next token (in this case the closing `]` as the second argument, thus only the `]` appears in blue, and none of what we expect to be in blue is coloured at all. If we want this command to work correctly, we then we need to protect the `[Arg1]` argument with braces so that the first `]` encountered parsing the optional argument is the second `]`. This is what output item 2 does.

The `xparse` defined command, however, is able to deal with this nesting without any extra braces, so both output items 3 and 4 show the output we expect even though item 3 uses the same surface syntax as item 1.

Comment: Maybe you can add that commands defined with `xparse` are usually able to correctly recognize nested optional arguments inside optional arguments.